# What post processing method was used to generate depth image as shown in the given example?

Tags: computer-vision, depth-image

The [32FN](https://github.com/ruirangerfan/Three-Filters-to-Normal?tab=readme-ov-file) method is a fast and effective method to estimate surface normal from a structured depth image. It appears the authors uses a "in-painting" method (please correct me if I am wrong) to smooth out the image for use. The images they showcased is from the [Augmented ICL NUIM](http://redwood-data.org/indoor/dataset.html) dataset

Is anyone familiar with the depth post-processing technique as shown in the following image

[image]

I looked for the technique that generates such depth images but so far haven't found it. Additionally, I have had no success in communicating with the authors to find out how they processed the depth images as of writing this post.

If you are familiar with the processing technique that results in such depth images, please share, I will appreciate it greatly.